# Can large pieces of slipware be dried without a kiln?

Tags: ceramics, clay

I have a clay (plasticine) positive of a human figure standing 5' tall

- Next step is making a rubber mold for the lost wax process and a bronze positive
- May I use the rubber mold for slip after the wax positive is made, plaster is to fragile and not at all charming
- Is Raku the answer for drying, if I can make a slip positive
- Would someone discuss the basics here?  Any pointers are welcomed, if they reference the project!
- The actual mold has multiple pieces that will be joined to form a container into which the slip may be poured and later poured out when the piece reaches the desired thickness.
- Suggestions on thickness and etc.
- Ideas other than plaster or slip

Comment: Five feet tall?

Comment: @Catija Yes, five feet tall.  Will be a complicated mold but, if memory serves me well, it will turn out fine.

Comment: 5 ft tall is well beyond the size for lost wax casting ; 5 in. is more like it.

Answer (score 1):

Making a piece out of ceramics, you should use plaster for the mold as it draws out the moisture from the clay slip, and you will not  need to  wait a  long  time to get the thickness of your  clay.  If you use a rubber mold, the moisture has to leave the clay through the  air, which is very slow.

Raku is a way to fire the clay, so unless you want a hardened piece out of the clay, I would not fire it raku style or otherwise.

If you are wanting to make a bronze piece, why use the ceramic as part? You can make the finished piece in several parts of bronze or clay.  The pieces  can  be  combined  afterward; molded clay glued with slip, or welding or soldering the bronze.

Another way would be a breakable mold for the entire piece, where you break the complete work out of the mold in one piece.

Comment: I tried to clean up the grammar and punctuation but I'm not sure this is accurate for what you want to say.  Please review the edit and modify anything where I didn't get it right.